# Is there a closed-form equation for $n!$? If not, why not?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, factorial, closed-form

I know that the Fibonacci sequence can be described via the Binet's formula.

However, I was wondering if there was a similar formula for $n!$.

**Is this possible?  If not, why not?**

Comment: $\Gamma(n+1)$... does it count? :p

Comment: It would be interesting to see an answer that does not involve integration.

Comment: Why do you not consider "n!" a closed form? :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR:  Well, because the n! is formally defined as $n!=\prod_{k=1}^n k$, which is not closed form.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression  `an expression is said to be a closed-form expression if, and only if, it can be expressed analytically in terms of a bounded number of certain "well-known" functions.`

Comment: @John Gietzen: Yes I know, but the point is, "n!" *is* usually considered among the "well-known" functions (and integrals often aren't!): it's conventional to say that you have a closed form solution even when it includes binomial coefficients $n \choose k$. Of course, the meaning of "closed form" always depends on which functions you include among "well-known", but I find the choice of omitting n! unconventional, hence the previous question with a smiley.

Comment: I have retagged the question because you are looking for efficient algorithms - not a "closed form". I hope you update the question too.

Comment: I believe OP means one in elementary terms. A better contrast: there is a well known elementary "closed-form" for iterative addition (the triangular numbers) so why is there not a "closed-form" for iterative multiplication?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're willing to accept an integral as an answer, then $n! = \int_0^\infty t^n e^{-t} \: dt$.

Comment: for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: Really, I'm looking for something whose complexity to calculate is better than $O\left( n\right)$

Comment: @Akhil, log(n!) is not in O(n) -- [look at the graphs for the "derivative" of log(n!)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/derivative%20of%20log%28fac%20n%29.gif), that's all but flat in areas of interest.

Comment: @John, I assume you mean better than O(n) multiplications. The trivial lower bound is O(n log n) see comment above. If you need a way to calculate factorials, factor n!, and then multiply is generally better than the native method. See here http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Comment: @Mgccl, indeed I did.  I guess I was just assuming that multiplications on a modern PC is a single clock cycle.  That breaks down when dealing with large enough factorials that it would matter, tho.

Comment: @Akhil @Mgccl: If you are defining multiplication to be one operation, then how many bits the answer is proportional to is irrelevant; a straightforward n! calculation requires at least n k-bit multiplications.  The OP is asking if it can be done better than that.

Comment: OK, fair enough -- apologies for the silliness.

Comment: This is indeed the only possible correct answer, apparently: (from Wikipedia) `There is, in fact, no such simple solution for factorials; any combination of sums, products, powers, exponential functions, or logarithms  with a fixed number of terms will not suffice to express $n!$.`

Comment: Wikipedia does not cite a source for that claim

Comment: @BlueRaja: The proof is left to the reader.

Comment: This answer, while chosen as best, is hardly satisfying.

Comment: I know it's unsatisfying.

Comment: @John Gietzen: Nice quote.  But, as all computer scientists know, "any combination of sums, products, powers, exponential functions, or logarithms with a fixed number of terms will not suffice to express $n$," either!  (In our usual number systems, the number of terms needed to express a positive integer $n$ is asymptotically $\log(n)$.)

Answer (score 11):

The relative error of [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) gets arbitrarily small as n gets larger.

$$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

However, it is only an approximation, not a closed-form of $n!$

Comment: @Harry: What makes you think he *purposely* misspelled it?

Comment: @Daniel: Because he did it right after linking a page!

Answer (score 8):

Contrast these two methods for calculating n!:

- Counting permutations of a n-element set one-by-one (this is what n! counts), vs.
- Multiplying together the numbers 1,2,...,n.

Therefore n! represents an amazingly efficient method for counting permutations!  So I think (and I don't think I'm the only one) that n! should probably be considered a closed form (unless you have some other clear definition of what constitutes a "closed" form).

For further reading, I recommend:  H. S. Wilf, What is an answer?, Amer. Math. Monthly, 89 (1982), pp. 289–292, [DOI: 10.2307/2321713](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2321713), [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2321713).

Comment: For the interested: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2321713

Comment: Article behind paywall.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Pure, unadulterated, raw information usually is. Despite the fact its inherent to the universe, anyone could conceivably discover the laws... someone in academia (where peer review is supposedly important and vital) tries to horde the information from others. Inexplicable and anti-intellectual

Answer (score 4):

This is a riff on some of the comments about what might constitute an "answer" and what "closed form" might mean: although it's somewhat facetious, it's intended to prompt thoughts about these issues.

Our base-10 number system interprets a string ${a_n}{a_{n-1}} \cdots {a_0}$ as the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i 10^i $ (which can be, and is, computed recursively as $a_0 + 10 \left( a_1 + 10 \left( \cdots + 10 a_n \right) \cdots \right)$).  If you take the former to be an acceptable "closed form" representation, then why not use a slight modification of this number system?  Specifically, interpret the same string as equal to $a_0 + 2 \left( a_1 + 3 \left( \cdots + (n+1) a_n \right) \cdots \right)$ and require that $0 \le a_0 \le 1, 0 \le a_1 \le 2, \ldots, 0 \le a_n \le n$.  In this "factorial" number system, $n! = 10 \cdots 0$ is represented as a simple $n$-digit string: it's "closed"!